# Extracting JSON text file to a table using PHP

Tags: php, json, text

I have a json file that I want to read with PHP

http://rh.ernestek.cz.cc/webeast/static.txt

I wanted to extract the "id" and the "key"

I wanted to loop through the id and key so that I can produce a table like this:

```
ID      Key
1       9d07d681e0c1e294264724f7726e6f6f29
3       9cd1e3a4a04b5208862c3140046f73b515
...
```

I tried to extract the first id and key out using the following code but no luck:

```
    <?php
    $json = file_get_contents('static.txt');
    $json_decoded = json_decode($json);
    echo "ID: ".$json_decoded->static->1->id."<br />";
    echo "Key: ".$json_decoded->static->1->key."<br />";
    ?>
```

Is there anything I an wrong?
Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: What is being displayed? Can you update your answer with what you're getting?

Comment: I adopted HamZa DzCyberDeV nice code and here is the result: http://rh.ernestek.cz.cc/webeast/trial.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `true` in `json_decode()` it will convert all objects to array:

```
$json = file_get_contents("http://rh.ernestek.cz.cc/webeast/static.txt");
$json_decoded = json_decode($json, true); // return array

$table = array();
foreach($json_decoded["static"] as $array){
    $table[$array["id"]] = $array["key"];
}

//creating the table for output
$output = '<table border="1"><tr><td>ID</td><td>Key</td></tr>';
foreach($table as $id => $key){
    $output .= "<tr><td>$id</td><td>$key</td></tr>";
}
$output .= '</table>';
echo $output;
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
I am sorry but I don't really understand what is this line doing "$table[$array["id"]] = $array["key"];"

It opens a 2 dimensional array with id and key?

What if now I want my table only includes the entries with "catched: 0" in the json file, how should I edit the code?

Thanks again!

Comment: @user2215892 `$array["id"]` is the ID and `$array["key"]` is the KEY right ? I've created an empty array `$table`, by doing the following `$table[$array["id"]] = $array["key"];` I'm assigning the ID as the key of the array and giving it the value KEY. You'll understand if you try the following `echo '<pre>'; print_r($table);echo '</pre>';`

Comment: Sorry that I asked a silly question. See what you mean. Thanks!
This method works simply because id is a number and it is just a simple array.

Great thanks! You saved my night from compiling the table. :)

Comment: @user2215892 Ah don't worry, even if the ID was a string it would have worked, you're welcome anyways :)

Answer (score 1):

Decode the json as an array (pass `true` as second parameter), and loop over the array like so

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('static.txt');
$json_decoded = json_decode($json, true);
foreach ($json_decoded['static'] as $item) {
     echo 'ID: ', $item['id'], '<br/>';
     echo 'Key: ', $item['key'], '<br/>';
}
```